# Conditional Left Join SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
table A 
    ----------------------------
    NAME   | CODE  | BRANCH
    ----------------------------
    bob    | PL    | B
    david  | AA    | B
    susan  | PL    | C
    joe    | AB    | C
    alfred | PL    | B

table B 
    ----------------------------
    CODE | DESCRIPTION
    ----------------------------
    PL   | code 1
    PB   | code 2 
    PC   | code 3

table C 
    ----------------------------
    CODE | DESCRIPTION
    ----------------------------
    AA   | code 4
    AB   | code 5 
    AC   | code 6
```

Is there any way to join table A, B and C. without join all the table?

```
select A.*, COALESCE(B.DESCRIPTION, C.DESCRIPTION) AS DESCRIPTION  from A 
left join B on A.CODE = B.CODE
left join C on A.CODE = C.CODE
```

In my real case there will be more than 10 to join with the same column.
So I need conditional left join, something like this

```
SELECT A* , DESCRIPTION
FROM A  LEFT JOIN (
     CASE
        WHEN A.CODE = 'B' THEN SELECT * FROM B
        WHEN A.CODE = 'C' THEN SELECT * FROM C
      END  
    ) BC ON A.CODE = BC.CODE
```

Comment: It's usually better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the ON clause.

Comment: I believe dynamic sql is what you want in this case. This will help you to begin with it:https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: Do you mind giving me the example through sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `CASE` to implement flow control. In SQL `CASE` is an expression that returns a single value.

You can instead use the following query:

```
select A.*, 
       CASE A.BRANCH
          WHEN 'B' THEN B.DESCRIPTION
          WHEN 'C' THEN C.DESCRIPTION
       END AS DESCRIPTION  
from A
left join B on A.CODE = B.CODE AND A.BRANCH = 'B'
left join C on A.CODE = C.CODE AND A.BRANCH = 'C'
```

Comment: as in my question, I don't want to join all the table. I join table what I need based on column branch in table A.

Comment: so there will be only join 1 table

Comment: @muhnizar I'm afraid this is not possible

Comment: @muhnizar: But the records in table A have different branches, so different tables are involved. Or are you saying you only want to select records for branch 'B' for instance? Then do just that, only join table b and have `where a.branch = 'B'`. I suppose you are seeing a problem where there is none.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to generate queries. Then you write a PL/SQL block to loop through all these queries and execute dynamically to give you separate results.

```
SELECT    'SELECT A.* , DESCRIPTION
FROM TABLEA A  LEFT JOIN '
       || CASE WHEN A.BRANCH = 'B' THEN 'TABLEB B' END
       || CASE WHEN A.BRANCH = 'C' THEN 'TABLEC C' END
       || ' ON '
       || 'A.CODE = '
       || CASE WHEN A.BRANCH = 'B' THEN 'B.CODE' END
       || CASE WHEN A.BRANCH = 'C' THEN 'C.CODE' END
          v_query
  FROM TableA A;
```

**Output**

```
V_QUERY                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT A.* , DESCRIPTION
FROM TABLEA A  LEFT JOIN TABLEB B ON A.CODE = B.CODE   



SELECT A.* , DESCRIPTION
FROM TABLEA A  LEFT JOIN TABLEB B ON A.CODE = B.CODE   



SELECT A.* , DESCRIPTION
FROM TABLEA A  LEFT JOIN TABLEC C ON A.CODE = C.CODE   



SELECT A.* , DESCRIPTION
FROM TABLEA A  LEFT JOIN TABLEC C ON A.CODE = C.CODE   



SELECT A.* , DESCRIPTION
FROM TABLEA A  LEFT JOIN TABLEB B ON A.CODE = B.CODE
```